# SFTP Files Timestamp

Tags: datetime, sftp

We have a client SFTP using which we receive our files. The problem is that their SFTP behaves in a wierd way. All the folder and files in it has the same timestamp, even if the file is posted today it shows timestamp as 01/01/2013

How is this possible?

If i download the same files to my local it shows different timestamp (which i believe is the original timestamp for the files)

[image]

The Left side is my local and the right side is SFTP.

Is there any way to identify what are the files that are posted today directly from SFTP, during this conditions(Timestamp not updating).

We are looking for a way to have it automated but not sure how to do it in this scenario

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you talking about the SSH base protocol or Simple File Transfer Protocol? (Please notify @ me I don't check for answers)

Comment: @user2284570 it is SSH base protocol...

Comment: So I can't help you in this case... Sorry

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://serverfault.com/questions/469192

Comment: What filesystem are you on? What timestamp (most filesystems have more than one9 does your FTP client show? Is the timestamp (whichever it is) the same when viwed directly in a shell on the server?

Answer (score 14):

If you're using a command-line `sftp` client you can just use the `-p` configuration flag to preserve timestamps either when starting the `sftp` client or on download.

For example, doing this downloads all files in a directory and sets their timestamp to *now*:

```
sftp> mget *
```

Using the `-p` flag preserves the timestamps of the source, however:

```
sftp> mget -p *
```

I assume the graphical client you're using has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Typically for automated file transfers such as you described here I would recommend using `rsync`. `rsync` has the ability to only transfer what has changed and can preserve the timestamps. It has many options. It comes with Linux and the Mac. There likely is `rsync` for Windows if needed.